# Doing Aysnc tasks in AWS Lambda inside map loop

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, aws-lambda

I need to fetch user details from the database, where the user list is provided in an Array.

```
await userList.map(async (usr, index) => {
    let sql = "SELECT `id`,`email`, `firstname`, `lastname` FROM `users` WHERE `id` = '"+usr.user_id+"'";
    let user_info = await getData(sql,0);
    userData.push(userObj);
});
```

Get Data function :-

```
let getData = async (sql, params) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
          if (err){
                  reject(err);
          }
          connection.query(sql, params, (err, results) => {
              if (err){
                  reject(err);
              }
              connection.release();
              resolve(results);
          });
      });
  });
};
```

Now the problem is function is getting exited before the results are pulled from the database.

If I remove the loop & pull a single record everything is working fine.

But, i need to get data for all users.

Comment: 1) Can we assume `userData` is an empty array defined just above the `map` call? 2) What is the `userObj` you are pushing to `userData`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know if it helps:

```
await Promise.all(userList.map(async (usr, index) => {
let sql = "SELECT `id`,`email`, `firstname`, `lastname` FROM `users` WHERE `id` = '"+usr.user_id+"'";
   let user_info = await getData(sql,0);
    userData.push(user_info);
  }));
```

Comment: That doesn't make any difference, you can access the data without using `.then` as well.

Comment: It will give you promise in return and not the actual data.

Comment: It's not an issue, that part is working fine. See `https://jsfiddle.net/q9hp3unj/` execute & check console.

Comment: The reason it doesn't work is because you don't return the user info from the `map` function, so it will result in instant resolved promises that yield `undefined`. You should remove `userData.push(user_info)` and instead `return user_info`. Furthermore, there is no reason to `await` in the `map` function, since you don't do anything with the data. Returning the promise without awaiting the result is enough.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can avoid map and rather use a for loop to achieve the result.

You can try the below SO snippet, to see if this is the desired outcome you needed.

```js
getData = (userId) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve("user"+ userId); 
    }, 500)
  })
}


ids = [1,2,3];

//Final results
results = [];

async function getAllDataAsync(){
  for(let i = 0; i < ids.length; i++ ){
    let user_info = await getData(ids[i]);
    results.push(user_info);
  }
  return Promise.resolve(results);

}

async function start(){
  const res =  await getAllDataAsync();
  console.log(res);
  console.log("Got the results. Put rest of the logic here");
}

start();
console.log("Function will exit first");
```